# How can I add (define) more supported screen resolutions (so that I will be able to select them in Ubuntu configuration)?

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I have monitor connected through VGA-DVI adapter which recommended resolution is 1920 x 1080 @60Hz. It is labeled (in Ubuntu configuration) as Unrecognized.

Although my graphics card (GeForce GTX 645) supports 1920 x 1080 resolution, the maximum resolution which I can select in GUI configuration tool is 1024x768.

This issue occurs regardless of used graphics driver - in case of both default and proprietary Nvidia driver.

Typing [xrandr](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Dynamically_testing_different_resolutions) gives me:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
1024x768 60.00*
800x600 60.32 56.25
848x480 60.00
640x480 59.94
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Could you help me to define more allowed screen resolutions?

Answer (score 1):

I want to add 1920x1080 60Hz

```
cvt 1920 1080 60
```

generates lines for new mode definition:

> 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083
>   1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

which I use:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

And now I am able to chagne resolution.

Since xrandr doesn't remember settings after session restart, I created a script which I run at each startup. Script consist following lines:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
```